# Infer interface type argument in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, type-inference

Let's have a following code:

```js
interface Action {
  type: string;
}

interface ActionA extends Action {
  type: 'A';
  payload: number;
}

interface ActionB extends Action {
  type: 'B';
  payload: string;
}

interface Processor<T extends Action> {
  action: T;
  process: (action: T) => void;
}

// usage

const actionA: ActionA = { type: 'A', payload: 42 };

const processorA: Processor<ActionA> = {
  action: actionA,
  process(action) {
    // ...
  },
};
```

Now I think that specifying type argument `ActionA` in `const processorA: Processor<ActionA> = ...` is redundant as it could be inferred from `action: ActionA`. Unfortunately Typescript reports error if I write just `const processorA: Processor = ...`.

Is it possible to improve interfaces so that type argument of `Processor` would be inferred?

**Advanced version:**

I would also like `action` field to be of type `T | '*'`. In that case `action` parameter of `process(action)` should be of type `Action` (or in worst case just `any`). Is this possible together with above mentioned type parameter inferring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way in typescript to infer part of a variable type. For variables inference is all or nothing, you either let the compiler infer it, or you specify it in a type annotation.

You can use a function to infer the type of the action:

```
function createProcessor<T extends Action>(p: Processor<T>) {
    return p
}
const processorA = createProcessor({
  action: actionA,
  process(action) {
    // ...
  },
});
```

Or you can use an IIFE as a kind of fancy type assertion:

```
const processorA = (<T extends Action>(p: Processor<T>) => p)({
  action: actionA,
  process(action) {
    // ...
  },
});
```

Comment: After introducing `createProcessor` tsc stucks. Offtopic: is there a way to profile tsc to see what degrades its performance?